# create a sequence of number in .net for primary key sql

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone help me with creating a sequence of number in .net for primary key(SQL server). I need to achieve this functionality through .net code. Has anyone ever tried this before?

Comment: Many times, PKs that are 'created' in .NET code are `GUID` data types.  Is this OK for your situation?

Comment: Have you ever heard of IDENTITY Columns? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Comment: _"I need to achieve this functionality through .net code"_
Why, you can [set IDENTITY_INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) which is safer than to inject a value programmatically(consider that multiple applications/threads are trying to insert simultaneously).

Comment: If you need a client side generated unique ID that still has sequential sort properties in SQL Server you may want to opt for a Comb Guid, as e.g. implemented in NHibernate: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Id/GuidCombGenerator.cs. I agree that if you are already tied to SQL Server it would make more sense to have SQL Server generate the IDs for you.

Comment: Job interview tests all the way through today.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of data with your PK column called RecordID and you want to get the next available one you could do something like this:

```
var nextId = table.OrderByDescending(x => x.RecordID).First().RecordID++;
```

However its not perfect as a user could delete the newest record freeing up the RecordID to be re-used. If you have other data that refers to it then it could end up pointing at a different record.

I think @David Tansey's comment was the best advice - use a GUID:

```
var nextId = Guid.NewGuid();
```